# Relative paths in Windows Forms application

Tags: .net, relative-path

I'm in Visual Studio, making a Windows Forms application. I'm having some difficulties with the relative paths. 
For example, connecting to a database, with an OleDbConnection, with a relative path of "\Databases\bla.mdb" works great while debugging from Visual Studio. However, if the executable path is somepath\Debug\app.exe, the database is actually in somepath\Databases\bla.mdb"

Where's the setting that defines that "base path" that's being used? 
I checked for Application::CommonAppDataPath, ExecutablePath, StartupPath, UserAppDataPath and LocalUserAppDataPath, none returns "somepath".

The final idea is that the Databases folder will be in the same folder as the executable, but if I hardcode that with ExecutablePath or something like that, it doesn't work while debugging... And if I leave it as is, in my computer it works fine (debugging and deployed with the Databases folder in the same folder as the .exe) but I tried it in another laptop and it searches for the Databases folder somewhere inside `My Documents`.

I'd appreciate any advice, answers or orientation. My googling hasn't been helpful so far

Comment: The path were database reside should be written in a configuration file. Your setup should update that file/path after deployment. The key benfits are: No more hassle to divine it inside the application, easy management should the need to move arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The final idea is that the Databases folder will be in the same folder as the executable

Meaning your debug directory layout is not the same as your deployment directory layout?

That's not a good plan. Instead of trying to "re-base" the root directory of your application for relative paths in debug vs deployment, you should try and match the directory layout for both scenarios.

Comment: I think he's running into the issue where the Application.Startup path is inconsistent depending on how the program is launched.  For example, from a scheduled task if the StartupDirectory isn't the same as the executable's directory.  There are a few goofy things that can mess it up.

Comment: This line really caught my attention though - " the executable path is somepath\Debug\app.exe, the database is actually in somepath\Databases\bla.mdb" "

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right, the layouts aren't the same. The deployment directory layout is the same as the "somepath" directory, but the debug directory is in "somepath/debug".

Comment: I started coding using relative paths everywhere and they all used "somepath" as the base directory while debugging so I forgot about it. I guess now I'll be using absolute paths now and move everything inside "somepath\debug".

Comment: I accepted this one because you addressed the real issue. But, actually, I did against your advice and re-base'd the current directory. I know too little and have too little time to dare fight against Visual Studio's automatic defaults, and if my directory layout is like that, that's entirely VS's fault.

Comment: Sounds like a pragmatic approach. You've got to pick your fights. :)

Answer (score 2):

[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx) will get you the executable's root directory as a string.  I usually use it with System.IO.Path.Combine as in

```
string DbLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Databases\bla.mdb");
```

You'll need a using statement for System.Reflection for it to work.

Comment: So, you agree that I should move all my resources into a subfolder inside the "somepath/Debug" directory, where the executable is, and then use absolute paths, built up with AppDomain.Cu.... So, if I ever want to test from VS in Release mode, I should duplicate the resources in "somepath/Release"?

Comment: No.  I think it should be in a different folder.  Storing it in that folder runs the risk of overwriting it if you ever update the client and you're not careful.  Your .mdb would then overwrite the one they've been storing data in.  I just answered the question at hand, which was how to find a file relative to the executable.  Personally, I'd store the .mdb anywhere else on the hard drive, or use SQL Server Express instead.

Comment: Presumably any setup package is going to need to determine whether it's a fresh or update install though to know whether it should try and install a "default" database. In which case, storing it in a different directory either puts you in the same situation, or adds an additional complexity of a second step for getting a "first install" database in place.

Answer (score 1):

In your application you should prefer absolute paths for safety.

Like you find out, if relative path are used, then a simple change of the startup folder of your application may change your target path completely. The startup folder may or may not be the folder that contains your executable, and it is almost out of your control (as the end users can freely execute your executable under any folder they like at command prompt).

Therefore, you may use what David recommends to form absolute paths from relative paths. You may also use a library such as http://filedirectorypath.codeplex.com/